# Matlab/Simulink - IN/OUT doesn't work with scopes

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink

I have a problem with Simulink, I created Simulink model, and to make it more understandable I want to use In and Out blocks and connect them with scope, but that doesn't work properly. Values don't go through this operation and scope is empty.

Values in whole model are good, on other connected scope everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Inport` are used to get external data into a model.  `Outport` are used to pass data generated by the model out externally (i.e. back into MATLAB).

If you have an `Inport`, and you don't set up data to be passed into your model, then the signal attached to the `Inport` will be zero.  It sounds as if this is what you have done.

From your description it sounds as if you are wanting the `GoTo` and `From` blocks.